# Coingecko links properties can't be accessed

Tags: javascript, coingecko

I'm using the following way to access a property on coingecko's API:
`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins`, this returns all crypto coins and their properties.

While using the above link I can access the IDs of any object in the response. but if I'm using the next link:
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin I'm still getting the ID as I can see in response, but I can't access the id like this: `data[index].id` (which I can do with the first link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second rest call returns an *object*, whereas the first link returns an *array of objects*.

To access `id` in the second example, simply use `data.id` (no array, so no index here).